# Notepad++ regex group capture

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have such txt file:

```
ххх.prontube.ru
salo.ru
bbb.antichat.ru
yyy.ru
xx.bb.prontube.ru
zzz.com
srfsf.jwbefw.com.ua
```

Trying to delete all subdomains with such regex:

```
Find:    .+\.((.*?)\.(ru|ua|com\.ua|com|net|info))$
Replace with: \1
```

Receive:

```
prontube.ru
salo.ru
antichat.ru
yyy.ru
prontube.ru
zzz.com
com.ua
```

Why last line becomes `com.ua` instead of `jwbefw.com.ua` ?

Answer (score 67):

This works without look around:

Find: `[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+\.([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$`
Replace: `\1\.\2`

It finds something with at least 2 periods and only letters, numbers, and dashes following the last two periods; then it replaces it with the last 2 parts. More intuitive, in my opinion.

There's something funny going on with that leading `xxx`. It doesn't appear to be plain ASCII. For the sake of this question, I'm going to assume that's just something funny with this site and not representative of your real data.

#### Incorrect

Interestingly, I previously had an incorrect answer here that accumulated a lot of upvotes. So I think I should preserve it:

Find: `[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.(.+)$`
Replace: `\1\.\2`

It just finds a host name with at least 2 periods in it, then replaces it with everything after the first dot.

Answer (score 10):

The `.+` part is matching as much as possible. Try using `.+?` instead, and it will capture the least possible, allowing the `com.ua` option to match.

Answer (score 1):

```
.+?\.([\w-]*?\.(?:ru|ua|com\.ua|com|net|info))$
```

This answer still uses the specific domain names that the original question was looking at.  As some TLD (top level domains) have a period in them, and you could theoretically have a list including multiple subdomains, whitelisting the TLD in the regex is a good idea if it works with your data set.  Both current answers (from 2013) will not handle the difference between "xx.bb.prontube.ru" and "srfsf.jwbefw.com.ua" correctly.

Here is a quick explanation of why this psnig's original regex isn't working as intended:
The `+` is greedy.
`.+` will zip all the way to the right at the end of the line capturing everything,
then work its way backwards (to the left) looking for a match from here:

`(ru|ua|com\.ua|com|net|info)`

With **srfsf.jwbefw.com.ua** the regex engine will first fail to match `a`, 
then it will move the token one place to the left to look at "ua" 
At that point, `ua` from the regex (the second option) is a match.

The engine will not keep looking to find "com.ua"  because ".ua" met that requirement.

Niet the Dark Absol's answer tells the regex to be "lazy"
`.+?` will match any character (at least one) and then try to find the next part of the regex.  If that fails, it will advance the token, `.+` matching one more character and then evaluating the rest of the regex again.
The .+? will eventually consume: **srfsf.jwbefw** before matching the period, and then matching **com.ua**.

But the implimentation of `?` also creates issues.

Adding in the question mark makes that first .+ lazy, but then causes group1 to match **bb.prontube.ru** instead of **prontube.ru**

This is because that first period after the bb will match, then inside group 1 `(.*?)` will match **bb.prontube**. before `\.(ru|ua|com\.ua|com|net|info))$` matches **.ru**

To avoid this, change that third group from `(.*?)`  to `([\w-]*?)`  so it won't capture **.** only letters and numbers, or a dash.

resulting regex:
**`.+?\.(([\w-])*?\.(ru|ua|com\.ua|com|net|info))$`**

Note that you don't need to capture any groups other than the first.  Adding ?: makes the TLD options non-capturing.

last change:
**`.+?\.([\w-]*?\.(?:ru|ua|com\.ua|com|net|info))$`**

Answer (score 1):

Search what: `.+?\.(\w+\.(?:ru|com|com\.au))`
Replace with: `$1`

Look in the picture above,  what regex capture referring
It's color the way you will not need a regex explaination anymore ....

[image]